# STM32H7 not utilizing the 480MHz PLL clock

Tags: stm32, clock

hope y'all are doing well.

I am currently trying to get my STM32H753ZIT6U to 480MHz as its the max clock frequency it can achieve, however when doing the procedure to change the frequency I am not getting what I am expecting. Any feedback is appreciated thanks.

I wrote a little dummy delay loop to test if the frequency is at 480MHz. I have the delay for 1 second, however through debugging it returns every 2 seconds indicating the frequency is not at 480MHz but suggesting around 240MHz.

The code for my dummy delay loop can be seen here: Where delay is equal to 1000000

```
void delayMicrosecond(uint32_t delay) {

    uint32_t cnt = 0;
    uint32_t delayCount = (double)(delay*1e-6)*(double)480e6;

    while (cnt < delayCount) {
        cnt++;
    }
}
```

The procedure I preformed to get to 480MHz are:

1. Changing the VOS scaling
2. Changing Flash wait cycles
3. Changing PLL1 P M N factors

The code can be seen here:

```
   LL_PWR_ConfigSupply(LL_PWR_LDO_SUPPLY);

    LL_PWR_SetRegulVoltageScaling(LL_PWR_REGU_VOLTAGE_SCALE1);
    while(LL_PWR_IsActiveFlag_VOS() == 0);

    LL_APB4_GRP1_EnableClock(LL_APB4_GRP1_PERIPH_SYSCFG);
    SYSCFG_PWRCR_REG |= (0x01 << 0);

    LL_PWR_ConfigSupply(LL_PWR_LDO_SUPPLY);

    FLASH_ACR_REG &= ~(0x3F << 0);
    FLASH_ACR_REG |=  (0x3C << 0);

    LL_RCC_PLL_SetSource(LL_RCC_PLLSOURCE_HSI);
    LL_RCC_PLL1_SetM(4);
    LL_RCC_PLL1_SetVCOInputRange(LL_RCC_PLLINPUTRANGE_8_16);
    LL_RCC_PLL1_SetVCOOutputRange(LL_RCC_PLLVCORANGE_WIDE);
    LL_RCC_PLL1P_Enable();
    LL_RCC_PLL1_SetP(2);
    LL_RCC_PLL1_SetN(60);

    LL_RCC_PLL1_Enable();
    while(LL_RCC_PLL1_IsReady() == 0);

    LL_RCC_SetSysPrescaler(LL_RCC_SYSCLK_DIV_1);
    LL_RCC_SetAHBPrescaler(LL_RCC_AHB_DIV_2);
    LL_RCC_SetAPB1Prescaler(LL_RCC_APB1_DIV_2);
    LL_RCC_SetAPB2Prescaler(LL_RCC_APB2_DIV_2);
    LL_RCC_SetAPB3Prescaler(LL_RCC_APB3_DIV_2);
    LL_RCC_SetAPB4Prescaler(LL_RCC_APB4_DIV_2);
    LL_RCC_SetSysClkSource(LL_RCC_SYS_CLKSOURCE_PLL1);
```

What I have testing so far:

1. Placing delayMicrosecond function into Ram, same results
2. Have MCO2 outputted to see if PLL1 is truley clocked at 480MHz, shown in the picture below, Divided by 4 to respect the max frequency of the GPIO pin. So 120MHz * 4 = 480MHz.
   [image]

Comment: You're assuming the entire loop body, including branch back to the beginning of the loop, executes in exactly one clock cycle?

Comment: Yes sir, the assumption is correct. I was thinking this assuming instructions are excuted in one cycle so I referenced the programming manuel and cant find anything on the cycles each instruction gives. If this is the case then I guess a dummy delay while loop is not sufficient enough?

Comment: Yes, an ARM Cortex M7 processor is well beyond the point of complexity where more than a handful of instructions have a constant latency. And you haven't even looked at the instructions that loop compiled into...  You should use a timer peripheral for this test -- although it still may not be able to run at the full speed of MCLK, it will at least be perfectly predictable, unaffected by previous cache contents or contention for system bus or branch predictor warmup or preemption by interrupts. Those things will still affect *handling* the timer event, but that's once instead of every loop pass

Comment: Thank you for your input, ill move the architecture from software into hardware.

Comment: @Leoc your code will compile to plenty of instructions in one loop (or to nothing  if you enable optimizations)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your expectation how software runs on an MCU is wrong.

If MCO is configured to have SYSCLK divided by 4 and you measure 120 MHz, then you have 480 MHz SYSCLK for sure.

Another way to demonstrate this is to utilize timers. Assuming the MCU runs at some frequency, you can use timers (in multiple different ways which are not important to list here) and blink a LED or toggle an IO pin at some rate, for example with 1 second period or 1 kHz frequency. Then measure at what rate the pin is toggling.

Comment: Thank you for putting into words of the issue I was having. My assumption of having instructions executed in one cycle is incorrect. Will move from software into hardware. And thank you for confirming the MHz SYSCLK.

Comment: @Leoc do you know how many instructions you have in the loop?

Answer (score 2):

Your code is definitely not executing the way you think it is.

1. If you compile your code with the optimizations enabled your code will be optimized to the single return instruction.

```
delayMicrosecond:
        @ args = 0, pretend = 0, frame = 0
        @ frame_needed = 0, uses_anonymous_args = 0
        @ link register save eliminated.
        bx      lr
```

Because if you observe some delay - you compile with optimizations disabled:

```
delayMicrosecond:
        push    {r7}
        sub     sp, sp, #20
        add     r7, sp, #0
        str     r0, [r7, #4]
        movs    r3, #0
        str     r3, [r7, #12]
        ldr     r3, [r7, #4]
        vmov    s15, r3 @ int
        vcvt.f64.u32    d7, s15
        vldr.64 d6, .L4
        vmul.f64        d7, d7, d6
        vcvt.u32.f64    s15, d7
        vmov    r3, s15 @ int
        str     r3, [r7, #8]
        b       .L2
.L3:
        ldr     r3, [r7, #12]
        adds    r3, r3, #1
        str     r3, [r7, #12]
.L2:
        ldr     r2, [r7, #12]
        ldr     r3, [r7, #8]
        cmp     r2, r3
        bcc     .L3
        nop
        nop
        adds    r7, r7, #20
        mov     sp, r7
        ldr     r7, [sp], #4
        bx      lr
.L4:
        .word   0
        .word   1081999360
```

You can use the memory barrier to disable some optimizations (and have the code closer to your "target one":

```
void delayMicrosecond(uint32_t delay) {

    uint32_t cnt = 0;
    uint32_t delayCount = (double)(delay*1e-6)*(double)480e6;

    while (cnt < delayCount) {
        cnt++;asm("");
    }
}
```

and the resulting code:

```
delayMicrosecond:
        vmov    s15, r0 @ int
        vldr.64 d6, .L9
        vcvt.f64.u32    d7, s15
        vmul.f64        d7, d7, d6
        vcvt.u32.f64    s15, d7
        vmov    r2, s15 @ int
        cbz     r2, .L1
        movs    r3, #0
.L3:
        adds    r3, r3, #1
        cmp     r2, r3
        bne     .L3
.L1:
        bx      lr
.L9:
        .word   0
        .word   1081999360
```

https://godbolt.org/z/YET56haqY